# PHP Warning: Unknown: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/index.php) is not within the allowed path(s)

Tags: php, apache2

при открытии `localhost` в браузере ошибка 500.
В `error.log` выводит такое:

```
PHP Warning:  Unknown: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/index.php) is not within the allowed path(s):(/usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/php/php-php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/:/usr/share/php/tcpdf/:/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/phpseclib/) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/index.php' (include_path='.') in Unknown on line 0.
```

Директива `open_basedir` в файле php.ini пустая и закомментирована.
Сам `index.php` просто выводит `phpinfo`.
При вызове в терминале всё работает.

Apache/2.4.38 (Debian 10)
Server built:   2020-08-25T20:08:29

PHP 7.4.10 (cli) (built: Sep  9 2020 06:54:34) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies with Zend OPcache v7.4.10, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

Comment: Php.ini может быть разный для консольного приложения, и для CGI (PHP-FPM).

Comment: для cli и cgi директива одинаково закомменчена

Answer (score 0):

Получилось решить так:

1. В директиве open_basedir в файле php.ini нужно прописать правильный путь к папке, в которой расположен файл .php
2. Перезапустить IIS (т.е. в окне слева выделить название сервера, а в окне "Действия (управление сервером)" - нажать "Перезапустить" )

Comment: Не увидел, что у вас apache2, а у меня IIS, но ошибка один в один. Правда разрешенные папки другие. В вашем случае нужно искать правильный файл .ini , содержащий именно эти ограничения. Он должен найтись.